# Make javascript do stuff on external pages

Tags: javascript

Ok so im learning javascript and I just wanted to know if its possible to make it do actions on external pages. For example if I wanted to say 'onload redirect to somesite.com/page1 then once on somesite.com/page1 fill in register form with these details'

is that possible?

Comment: You can only make it do *stuff* on the current page, but you can redirect to another page *and then* make the javascript on **that** page do stuff etc.

Comment: If you own the other page, there's things you can do. If you don't own the other page, there's nothing you can do. (For very good security based reasons)

Comment: If you need to do stuff on external pages, your probably doing something wrong in the first place.

Comment: I just want to prefill out some of the form for my users when they signup. like type yes if you want to receive our monthly newsletter etc and have it prefilled with 'yes'

Comment: You could make it very simple and send the data you want to fill in via the URL as a GET parameter. The other page then has to read the parameter and fill the form. This could be done server or client side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.
This would represent, for lack of a better word, an **enormous** security hole. 
The only way to make an external page "do stuff" is to write code that is on or explicitly included in that page itself. Period.

I have however, seen external pages get loaded INTO the current page as strings, and then have the javascript that loaded those pages modify that markup directly. But that is **ugly**.

Answer (score 0):

On the first page you could modify some variables/values in a database. Then, in the second page you could check the values in your database, and do different "stuff" depending on those values.

You would need to set up a database and use some server-side scripting along with Javascript (server-side scripting is used to interact with your server/database). In your first page, the server-side script, like PHP, would fetch info from your Javascript. In your second page, your Javascript would fetch info from your server side script and then do stuff to that page.

This is a much safer way. If you are taking user input from things like HTML fields, you need to look into cleaning the input to prevent something called "cross-site scripting (XSS)".

Answer (score 0):

You could do this IF you were rendering the other page in a frame of some sort.

There are multiple ways in which you can render an entire external page as a piece of your page. Many pages take precautions to block being rendered in a frame for just this very reason though (Not to mention copyright issues).

Once you're rendering the external page inside your page you should be able to reference components nested in your frame and do the sort of thing that you're describing.

Comment: Yeah but the example states "onload redirect to somesite.com/page1" implying an external redirect. Either way this is a bad idea and indicates poor application design.

Comment: as @dudewad said, this will be ugly and a bad idea... but you could

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with JavaScript. The developers of all the major browsers work very, *very* hard to prevent this sort of thing. If this were possible, it would open up pretty massive security holes.

If you really want to use something like this for testing, you can look at browser automation software like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). This allows you to automate various testing scenarios in your browser, but it does not affect other clients using your site.